# Boost Async Websocket Server Issue

Tags: boost-asio, boost-beast, beast-websockets

I've wrote an async websocket thru boost.beast. But when I try to run it, I cannot connect it.

The server code like below. When I try to connect my websocket server, my chrome shows status connecting.
When I debug thru VS2017, it never run into the lambda expression in run().

```
iListener::iListener( boost::asio::io_context& ioc,boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint)  : acceptor_(ioc), socket_(ioc) {

    boost::system::error_code ec;

    std::cout<<"iListener"<<std::endl;
    // Open the acceptor
    acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol(), ec);
    if (ec) {
        // fail(ec, "open");
        return;
    }

    // Allow address reuse
    acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true), ec);
    if (ec) {
        // fail(ec, "set_option");
        return;
    }

    // Bind to the server address
    acceptor_.bind(endpoint, ec);
    if (ec) {
        // fail(ec, "bind");
        return;
    }

    // Start listening for connections
    acceptor_.listen(
            boost::asio::socket_base::max_listen_connections, ec);
    if (ec) {

        std::cout << ec.message() << "   listen" << std::endl;
        // fail(ec, "listen");
        return;
    }
}

iListener::~iListener() {

}

void iListener::run() {
    if (!acceptor_.is_open()) {
        return;
    }
    std::cout<<"iListener run"<<std::endl;
    while (true) {
        acceptor_.async_accept(socket_, [&](boost::system::error_code ec1) {
            std::cout << "now run listener" << std::endl;
            if (ec1) {
                std::cout<<ec1.message()<<"   accept"<<std::endl;
                // fail(ec, "accept");
            } else {
                // Create the session and run it
                std::make_shared<NormalSession>(std::move(socket_))->run();
            }
        });
    }


}

void iListener::initListener(const std::string &addressStr, unsigned short port, int threads){
    auto const address = boost::asio::ip::make_address(addressStr);
    boost::asio::io_context ioc{threads};
    std::make_shared<iListener>(ioc, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint{address, port})->run();
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    v.reserve(threads - 1);
    for(auto i = threads - 1; i > 0; --i)
        v.emplace_back(
                [&ioc]
                {
                    ioc.run();
                });
    ioc.run();
}
```

And when I try to connect it on Console of Chrome.
It taks a long time to connect, and then shows failed.

---

So I change back, as the example of boost.It  works.

```
void iListener::run() {
    if (!acceptor_.is_open()) {
        return;
    }
   // std::cout<<"iListener run"<<std::endl;
   // while (true) {
   //     acceptor_.async_accept(socket_, [&](boost::system::error_code ec1) {
            //std::cout << "now run listener" << std::endl;
   //         if (ec1) {
   //             std::cout<<ec1.message()<<"   accept"<<std::endl;
   //             // fail(ec, "accept");
   //         } else {
   //             // Create the session and run it
   //             std::make_shared<NormalSession>(std::move(socket_))->run();
   //         }
   //     });
   // }
    do_accept();

}

void iListener::do_accept() {
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        socket_,
        std::bind(
            &iListener::on_accept,
            shared_from_this(),
            std::placeholders::_1));
}

void    iListener::on_accept(boost::system::error_code ec) {
    if (ec)
    {
        std::cout << ec.message() << "   on_accept" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // Create the session and run it
        std::make_shared<NormalSession>(std::move(socket_))->run();
    }

    // Accept another connection
    do_accept();
}
```

I have two questions:

1.Why I use lambda, it will SOF , but example won't.
2.When I use while(), it not work, why? Is there any different between lambda expression and std::bind()??

---

So another question, what's different between two code blocks below?

```
void iListener::do_accept() {
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        socket_,
        [&](boost::system::error_code ec1) mutable {
        on_accept(ec1);
    }
}


void iListener::do_accept() {
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        socket_,
        std::bind(
            &iListener::on_accept,
            shared_from_this(),
            std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

When I use the top one, it return error_code 995.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

What is the difference between `bind` and `lambda`? In the former you prolong lifetime of `iListener` instance, in the latter you don't.

We need to start from this line:

```
std::make_shared<iListener>(ioc, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint{address, port})->run();
// [a]
```

if you don't extend lifetime of `iListener` in `run`, in [a] line `iListener` instance will be destroyed.

- std::bind

As one of params of bind you are passing `shared_from_this`, it creates `shared_ptr` from `this` pointer, so functor object returned by `bind` keeps smart pointer to `iListener` instance prolongs its lifetime.

- lambda

lifetime of `iListener` is not extended, you call `async_accept` passing lambda without increasing reference counter for the current object i.e. for which `do_accept` is called. So `async_accept` returns immediately, `do_accept` ends, finally `run` ends too, and object created by `std::make_shared<iListener>(ioc, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint{address, port})` is deleted.

You need to update ref counter by passing `shared_ptr` by value into your lambda:

```
void iListener::do_accept() {
    auto sp = shared_from_this();
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        socket_,
        [&,sp](boost::system::error_code ec1) mutable 
      {
        on_accept(ec1);
      }
}
```

---

Handler (in your case the body of lambda) for a task initiated by `async_accept` is called from `io_context::run`, you cannot see this execution because your code hangs on this line:

```
std::make_shared<iListener>(ioc, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint{address, port})->run();
```

this creates `iListener` instance and calls `run` which contains the infinite loop and never ends:

```
while (true) { // INFINITE LOOP
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket_, [&](boost::system::error_code ec1) {
        std::cout << "now run listener" << std::endl;
        if (ec1) {
            std::cout<<ec1.message()<<"   accept"<<std::endl;
            // fail(ec, "accept");
        } else {
            // Create the session and run it
            std::make_shared<NormalSession>(std::move(socket_))->run();
        }
    });
}
```

so you cannot reach the lines that starts `io_context::run` in which handlers can be called.

Fix: before starting `io_context::run` you can start another thread where `iListener::run` is executed.

Visit Boost Asio [examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html) to see how `async_accept` is used. Common way is to call `async_accept` from its handler, but if you want to do this, your `iListener` should derive from `enable_shared_from_this` to prolong its lifetime when passing into handler.

---

Another problem is with `socket_` data member. I assume you want to hold one socket per session, but now your code doesn't handle it correctly. You have only one instance of `socket_` which is moved into `NormalSession` if a new connection was established. So when `async_accept` is called second time you are passing INVALID socket. It cannot work. It leads to undefined behaviour.

After executing the line below

```
std::make_shared<NormalSession>(std::move(socket_))->run();
```

you can forget about `socket_`.

`async_accept` is overloaded, you can use the version taking [handler](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload3.html) with newly accepted socket.

But if you want to stay with the current version taking `socket`, you need to ensure that every time `async_accept` is called it takes unique instance of socket.

Comment: thank you for your explanation.I've done as you said, but it not works.
So I just do as example in Boost_168, that I change it to std::bind() rather than lambda. It works.
I wonder what does lambda differ than std::bin()?
Plz see the original question I edit

Comment: @vainman I edited my answer with explanation between bind and lambda.

Comment: I just found that bind function has shared_from_this, and then see your updated answer. It works. And I wanna know that why this code won't cause SOF? It looks like a recursion rather than a loop

Comment: You could have recursion and SOF when `on_accept` would be called from the same function, but in this case `on_accept` is called from handler, which is invoked somewhere in code of `io_context::run`. With lambda without shared_from_this you rather got segmentation fault, instead of stack overflow. `async_XXX` initiates task and returns immediately, so you cannot get SOF.

Comment: Explain crystally. The c++ code style is too complicated to understand. Thank you. I will read the source code of boost.

Comment: I've met another question, may I have your help? link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56147852/how-to-use-template-within-template-in-c11

Comment: Got it ,after read the source code, I read the comments in  teardown.hpp, I forget include #include <boost/beast/websocket/ssl.hpp>